# Apache to Nginx: how to translate htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

This is one of many rules i have in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^categories/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  types.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

**Question 1:** how do you translate that rule?

**Question 2:** does nginx have file similar to htaccess or is just the nginx.conf to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rewrite ^/categories/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /types.php?type=$1&id=$2 last;
```

The rewrite rule should translate easily, except that `nginx` uses a leading `/` on all URIs.

The `nginx.conf` is the starting point, but many installations use `include` directives to pull in configuration from other files.

The `rewrite` rule can be placed at `server` block scope or within a `location` block that processes URIs beginning with `/categories`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for `rewrite` syntax.